# Is it possible to use a CSS class inside the brackets of jquery's css()?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set the CSS of an element on the fly. Can I use a CSS class inside the brackets of JQuery's css()?

I've looked in http://api.jquery.com/css/ but can't find anything on it.

To be clear, rather than doing the following, with multiple CSS items:

```
    $("div").css("background-color":"yellow", "color":"blue");
```

I'd like to be able to do something along the lines of the following:

```
    $("div").css('.abc');
```

(where 'abc' is the class in a stylesheet that contains multiple CSS lines)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can.
But you can use :

`$("div").addClass("abc");`

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

And here's all the class attributes that you can use in jquery : [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`.addClass('abc')`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)? There is a whole suite of [related functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to add a class to the object.

```
$("div").addClass("abc");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this quite easily, but not with `.css`. You'll want to use `.addClass`.

It would look like this:

```
$('div').addClass('abc');
```

Note that you just need the class name, not the `.` before it.

There is also a `removeClass`, which, surprisingly enough, removes a class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need to remove the dot (hadn't spotted it until you did!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but :

- you can add a class to a div using `$('div').addClass('abc')` or `$('div').attr('class','abc')`
- you can set style for that class using `$('.abc').css(...)`
- you can set style for the divs with that class using `$('div.abc').css(...)`

Comment: wouldn't `.attr('class',...)` remove any other previously added classes?